# Python - nmap scan without looking for specific ports

Tags: python, nmap

Is it possible to start an nmap scan using python script that doesn't focus on available ports?

```
>>> import nmap
>>> nm = nmap.PortScanner()
>>> nm.scan('127.0.0.1', '22-443')
>>> nm.command_line()
'nmap -oX - -p 22-443 -sV 127.0.0.1'
```

This example requires a port, or a range of ports, to scan. With in a normal nmap scan from the linux terminal, it could be as simple as;

```
nmap -O -v <ip address/range>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass whatever arguments you want:

```
nm.scan(hosts='<ip address/range>',arguments="-O -v")
```

Bear in mind  fingerprinting will need root privileges.

If you are scanning a range of ip's `PortScannerAsync` might be useful:

```
import nmap

nm = nmap.PortScannerAsync()
def callback_result(host, scan_result):
    print '------------------'
    print host, scan_result

nm.scan('192.168.1.0/24', arguments="-O -v", callback=callback_result)
while nm.still_scanning():
    print("Waiting >>>")
    nm.wait(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tryed

```
>>> nm.scan('127.0.0.1')
```

? Because the ports argument is optional.